# tar error: Unexpected EOF in archive

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to extract large tar folders, using the tar command

```
tar -xvif v1-2-val.tar.gz
```

but I get the error

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

the output of `file v1-2-val.tar.gz`

```
v1-2_val.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Thu May  9 13:21:59 2019, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 2301755392 gzip compressed data, unknown method, ASCII, has CRC, encrypted, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), original size modulo 2^32 2301755392
```

I am able to get 10 or so uncompressed videos before it stops and shows the error, I want to skip any corrupted files and continue the process. I have searched the error, and tried different tar flags and re-downloading the folders, but nothing works, so I want to mention that the tar folders are the validation and testing set of ActivityNet, in case someone had an experience downloading the dataset.

Comment: The error seems to signify that it has nothing to do with tar. Maybe you can try `gunzip -k` and see. Also see if you can manage to test with some other versions of gzip, starting from trying 1.12 instead if you weren't using this latest version.